# Where I am going wrong in this stack operation?

Tags: c++, loops, stack, c++17

This is a snippet of my code, which is not terminating due to loop error. I want to check the array elements which is in the form of stack or not, this is an example caused error.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arr[]={5,4,3,2,1}, k=0;
    stack <int> s;
    for(int i=1; i<=5; i++)
    {
        s.push(i);
        while(s.top()==arr[k] && s.size()>0){
            s.pop();
            ++k;
        }
    }
    cout<<"finished";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting , could you please explain..

Comment: Stepping through the program with a debugger and watching how the variables in play change will break this wide open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that an empty stack has no `top()`.

```
    while(s.top()==arr[k] && s.size()>0){
```

The fix is to reverse the condition check.

```
    while(s.size()>0 && s.top()==arr[k]){
```